# using pcl_to_laserscan

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ethzasl-ptam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everybody,

i'm trying to use pointcloud_to_laserscan, for trasform the pointcloud that i obtain by the camera of a parrot, using ptam, and converting it for be able to visualize in Rviz.
i'd seen that pcl_to_laserscan use a launcher that depend from the node used etc... but i cannot find a decent tutorial for learn how to write this launchfile.
do someone had try to do that? or could help me understanding how to write the launchfile??

thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200709/using-pcl_to_laserscan/) by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2015-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found here - https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/tree/indigo-devel/pointcloud_to_laserscan/launch

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on 2015-01-12**:
thank you for your answer, but a tutorial is possible to find??
in the link i could see only a launchfile, but cannot understand how learn more on writing launchfiles.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-01-12**:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch

**Comment by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on 2015-01-13**:
Thank you very much!
but now i've another missing point, this openni2.launch, that give me an error if i run the linked launchfile, what is exactly??
i'd downloaded the percetion-pcl package and catkinized it, and it does not contain any openni named file.
could you link me wich packages i need for?

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-01-13**:
openni2.launch is the driver wrapper for kinect/xtion. You don't need it, the launch represents a sample pointcloud source.

**Comment by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on 2015-01-14**:
Thank you very much!